# Sufficient bound on variance for an inequality to hold

Tags: probability, inequality, probability-distributions, variance, fixed-points

Let $X$ be a continuous, unimodal, symmetrical random variable on $[0,1]$ with $EX=\frac{1}{2}$ and $\operatorname{Var} (X)=\sigma^2$. Let $f$ be $X$'s density, and $F$ - the corresponding cdf. I assume that $f(\frac{1}{2})$ is large, i.e. $f(\frac{1}{2})>\frac{1}{1-2a}$, where $0<a<\frac{1}{2}$ is some given parameter and $f(0)=f(1)=0$. I would also assume $f$ is increasing on $(0,1/2)$ [edit] and $f$ differentiable.

Assume $\bar{x}<1/2$ satisfies $\bar{x}=a+(1-2a)F(\bar{x})$ for same $a$ as above (notice that $\frac{1}{2}$ also satisfies this equation, but I am interested in the smaller solution).

I would like to determine under what conditions the following inequality would hold:
$$\operatorname{Var}(X)\leq \left (\frac{1}{2}-\bar{x}\right )^2$$

Notice that both sides depend on the variability of $x$. In particular, as $\operatorname{Var}(X)$ decreases and $X$ tends to Dirac's delta $\delta_{\frac{1}{2}}$, the LHS becomes small and the RHS becomes large, i.e. tends to $(\frac{1}{2}-a)^2.$ My intuition is that if $\operatorname{Var}(X)$ is "sufficiently bounded", the inequality would hold. However, I find it difficult to formalize what bound would help me.

[edit] My best intuition so far is to have a condition $\int_0^1 xF(x)<\epsilon$, but I do not know how to use it to say anything interesting about $\bar{x}$ (of course, we want to make $\bar{x}$ "small enough").

Comment: what exactly is $\bar{x}$? is it the sample mean? is it  a variable? $a$ seems to define your F. F is poorly defined for $\bar{x}<a$ since then $F(\bar{x})<0$ which should never happen. Can you clarify?

Comment: $\bar{x}$ is defined as a solution to the equation $x=a+(1-2a)F(x)$ with a constraint $x<1/2$. Notice that this equation has three solutions, $\bar{x}$ is the smallest one (the other are $\frac{1}{2}$ and $1-\bar{x}$.
$F$ is a cdf of a distribution, so it takes values between 0 and 1. And the only connection it has with $a$ (for now) is its derivative in one point only $f'(\frac{1}{2})>\frac{1}{1-2a}$.

Comment: I might have found a counter example. I think you should add that the pdf is differentiable everywhere. currently I could define a distribution where a suitably small interval is say around 50(but could be arbitrarly high as long as I make the interval small enough) and then for the rest of the support the pdf is somewhere around 0.99. the variance would be roughly 1/12 (uniform distribution) while i could make a (and with it $\bar{x}$) arbitrarily close to 0.5 making the right hand size arbitrarliy small.

Comment: To make it continous I would still need a function with a very high derivative right before the interval and with a very low derivative right after the interval. But that is just a question of defining very steep functions. I am able to glue these functions together because I do not have to make it differentiable

Comment: Ok, I can add differentiability. I already know that I cannot get "too close" to uniform distribution - for the inequality to work, I need a cdf that is - to put it informally -"close to 0 on a large interval". However, I have no idea how to make it more formal. My best intuition so far is a condition that $\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} xf(x)<\epsilon,$ but I just do not know how to utilize it to say anything about $\bar{x}$.

Comment: Sorry, it should be $\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}xF(x)<\epsilon$!

Comment: You can argue that if you can add a constraint like $\int_a^{1-a}f(x)\geq0.5+a $ you cannot reasonably have a very high variance

Comment: But that might be a too strong constraint

Comment: Well, the "best" solutions would be to find the weakest possible constraint. As for now, I am looking for any second-best solution that would give me the required inequality, with any "reasonable" constraint. Yours seem reasonable - would you like to post an answer with some argument on how it gives me "not very high" variance?

Comment: I derived a bound on the variance in terms of a but I couldn't make it work in terms of just $\bar{x}$ I am not sure that this is possible without some restriction in terms of $\bar{x}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I am going to reason why a $\int_a^{1-a}f(x)\geq 0.5+a$ type restriction is a useful type of restriction but apprently is is still not sufficient since I couldn't get rid of $F(\bar{x})$ . I'll use $\int_a^{1-a}f(x)\geq 0.5+a$ in this example because that is what I originally said but you can make make that 0.5 higher to get stronger bounds, notice however that than a also needs to be defined on an interval [0,1-b] and is no longer defined on [0,0.5] so for this a this is the strongest bound of this kind.
 It is hard to actually make this restriction work in general in terms of $\bar{x}$ I did derive an upperbound for the variance based on $a$ though which can be tranlsted into a bound in terms of $\bar{x}$ and $F(\bar{x})$ but I couldn't remove $F(\bar{x})$ and I am not aware of any way of doing that because it depends on both $a$ and $F(\bar{x})$ and without a second equation with all of them involved you can't get rid of both. Hopefully this does help though

So let's first start with that no always incrasing distribution can have a variance larger than the uniform distribution on the relevant interval. This takes care of the border case where $a$ goes to zero since $\operatorname{Var}(X)\leq 1/12 \leq \left (\frac{1}{2}-0\right )^2$.
 in fact we can use this further so let's assume x is not so close to zero than we can start to use our new restriction. First we use the definition of the variance $\operatorname{Var}(x)= \int (x-\mu)^2 f(x)dx$ now we can make that $\operatorname{Var}(x)= \int^{1}_{0} (x-\mu)^2 f(x)dx$ because we know the bounds of the domain. Then we can split that integral up into mutliple regions  so that $\operatorname{Var}(x)= \int^{a}_{0} (x-\mu)^2 f(x)dx+\int^{1-a}_{a} (x-\mu)^2 f(x)dx+\int^{1}_{1-a} (x-\mu)^2 f(x)dx$ because of symmetry we have $\operatorname{Var}(x)= 2\int^{a}_{0} (x-\mu)^2 f(x)dx+\int^{1-a}_{a} (x-\mu)^2 f(x)dx$

Now we can  calculate upperbounds over these terms. we can not calculate the size of those integrals exactly because we do not know f(x).
However since we know some things from our restriction we can derive an upperbound for each term.
Let's first note that all multiplicative terms are nonnegative so $(x-\mu)^2, f(x)\geq0$  this is important becauswe can say that given a positive function f(x) times another positive function g(x) that is smaller than 1 for all relevant values: $\int^{a}_{0} g(x) f(x) \leq \int^{a}_{0} f(x)$ so we know 
$\operatorname{Var}(x)= 2\int^{a}_{0} (x-\mu)^2 f(x)dx+\int^{1-a}_{a} (x-\mu)^2 f(x)dx \leq 2\int^{a}_{0}  f(x)dx+\int^{1-a}_{a} f(x)dx=1$ Now this gives as an upper bound but this is not really useful. But we can do better you say we can say that  $\int^{a}_{0} g(x) f(x)dx\leq\int^{a}_{0} \max_{x}(g(x)) f(x) dx\leq \int^{a}_{0} f(x)dx$.

so now we have a value we can evaluate that we know that $\int_a^{1-a}f(x)=0.5+a+b\geq 0.5+a$  with $b \geq 0$ a slack variable so we know that $\int^{1-a}_{a} (x-\mu)^2 f(x)dx \leq \max_{a\leq x\leq 1-a}(x-\mu)^2(0.5+a+b)$ and $2\int^{a}_{0} (x-\mu)^2 f(x)dx \leq 2 \max_{0\leq x\leq a}((x-\mu)^2)(1-(0.5+a+b))$ we can also easlily see that in the first the maximum expresiion evaluates to $(a-\mu)^2$ and in the second to $(0-\mu)^2$
so finally we can say $Var(x)\leq(a-\mu)^2(0.5+a+b)+2(\mu)^2(1-0.5-a-b)$

filling in $\mu$ we have a inequality for the variance
$Var(x)\leq(a-0.5)^2(0.5+a+b)+0.5(0.5-a-b)$ clearly the right hand side obtains it's maximum when b=0 because the negative coefficient for b in the second term is always larger than the positive coefficient in the first term therefore.
$Var(x)\leq(a-0.5)^2(0.5+a)+0.5(0.5-a)=a^3 - 0.5 a^2 - 0.75 a + 0.375$

Then we can fill in $a$ if we want $a=\dfrac{\bar{x}-F(\bar{x})}{1-2F(\bar{x})}$

Comment: Ok, sorry for late response, but I had not time to read it thoroughly. So, one thing puzzles me. You write:
$$\int_a^{1-a}(x-\mu)^2f(x)dx\leq \max(x-\mu)^2(0.5+a+b),$$
but this is not true, as we have a condition with inequality going the other way $\int_a^{1-a}f(x)dx\geq(0.5+a+b).$
For the other bound, it holds, as we have a minus there, but here it does not work.

Comment: @JoannaF sorry I think this misconception comes from my confusing use of $b$ , I changed it now and hopefully made it clearer. The inequality does hold however. $b$ is a slack variable and so by definition $\int_a^{1-a}f(x)dx=(0.5+a+b)$ this  means we work with an equality. that slack variable b stays in there until I show that it has to be 0.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. Thanks! I am still working on some more "universal" condition, but if I fail, this looks useful.